# How does the splitting in the Künneth theorem work?

Tags: homological-algebra

In the algebraic Künneth theorem, see
[https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Künneth+theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/K%C3%BCnneth+theorem) theorem 2.2
We assume we have two complexes, one of which is free over some PID.

Now this gives some short exact sequence whose left map is

$\oplus{H_k(C) \otimes H_{n-k}(C')} \to
\oplus {H_n(C \otimes C')} $
 And this injection is split noncanonically.

Now my question is about the proof of this splitting.

From all the sources I looked at, the first step is to notice the splitting of

$0 \to Z \to C \to B \to 0$

Now this induces a splitting after tensoring by $C'$ or $Z'$ however I cannot really finish the proof.

I would appreciate someone spelling out the details of the last bit, I looked at different sources but none are really detailed. Hatcher seems to assume C' are also free? Please do not assume any properties of C', the nLab statement doesn't impose any conditions on C'.

Edit: just realized nLab doesn't even talk about splitting... Rest assured that both Weibel and Rotman writes split for the conditions I gave

Comment: A detail that has its importance : I have transformed all the names you give in order they begin by a capital letter.

Comment: For any future readers, the proof is in Hilton and Stammbach, the proof applies five lemma to conclude the general case from the case of free modules